# my token in proper but still it is showing inproper

Tags: tkinter, discord, discord.py, clone, customtkinter

Actually, I am making a `discord` cloner. I want to connect that with `customtkinter`, but it got this error.

I think it got any problem with `str`. I need some help related to that.

```
client = client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=(prefix), intents = discord.Intents.all())

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode('dark')
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme('dark-blue')
window = customtkinter.CTk()
window.geometry('400x250')
window.title('discord server cloner -- unknown')
window.resizable(False,False)
frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=window,
width=400,
height=250,
corner_radius=10,
fg_color='transparent')
frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

#############################################################

font = ("Comic Sans MS", 20, "bold")
unknown = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master = frame, text="UNKNOWN's cloner", font=font)

sep = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame, text="")
sep1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame, text="")

token = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame, show='\*', placeholder_text="bot token")
butt = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame, text='next', command=lambda: frame.destroy())
unknown.pack()
sep.pack()

token.pack()
sep1.pack()
butt.pack()

TOKEN = (str(token.get()))

window.mainloop()
client.run(TOKEN)



"C:\\Users\\NC\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\discord\\http.py", line 805, in static_login
raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
```

Comment: _"but it got this error."_: What error..? Also, you are fetching the value from `token` as soon as its made (hence empty). Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72116805/13382000

Answer (score -1):

i think the problem with the `token` variable because if you are going to use Entry you must put at the end `textvariable`

```
token_var = StringVar()
token = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame, show='\*', placeholder_text="bot token", textvariable=token_var)
```

**NOTE : you must import everything in customtkinter `from customtkinter import *`**